# Why doesn't my jquery date-picker not work in my asp.net code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jquery datepicker in my asp.net page.  Somehow it isnt working  and i saw alot of answers and also the `jquery-ui's api` , and i see no difference in what different i am doing ..

Here is my `aspx` code :

```
  <div class="form-group"
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" Text="Event Date :" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="SlateBlue" Font-Size="Larger" />
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEventDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                 </div>
          </div>
```

My script is  :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtEventDate').datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                showButtonPanel: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Now , upon DOM inspection i found that the `ID` is not rendered as `txtEventDate` but as `ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEventDate`(**Note :** I am using a master page here. )

I do not know why exactly the script is not working . is that because of the rendered different `ID` ??

My jquery implementation  :

following are in masterpage :

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--common script for all pages-->
        <script src="assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>
```

And the one's i have included(just to be safe0 on the page where i am using `datepicker()` :

```
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Please have a look at the following errors .]

Comment: Yes that's the issue. You have to put the rendered ID to the datepicker method.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis: what is the solution to that?

Comment: Either you can put the rendered ID for creating datepicker instead of txtEventDate or you can set a CSS class for that textbox and use that instead of ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to change this:

```
 $('#txtEventDate').datepicker({
```

to:

```
$('#<%=txtEventDate.ClientID%>').datepicker({
```

That way it'll pick up the rendered ID correctly everytime

Comment: if you do `$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEventDate').datepicker({` does it work then?

Comment: can it be not working because of the api that i am using ? I am using an api which is in my template !

Comment: I don't think your JQuery UI is being loaded in correctly. Can you edit your question to include your JS and CSS implementation?

Comment: Please see i ve added a screenshot too.. There are 3 errors out of which one is of `js` .

Comment: add a css class to your text box and use that instead

Comment: I see that you're using a customised version of the Jquery UI - this could be the issue in that you're lacking the library code for the datepicker.  Try temporarily replacing it with `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`